# How do I resolve error : can only concatenate str (not “int”) to str yet I am adding string to a string

Tags: python, spyder

Line 96 on screen.
Getting error ,” can only concatenate str ( not “ int”) to str
fn on left is a string and on right is also a str (converting  interger into a string)

fn r c user tukay onedrive desktop temp test.csv string i+1 csv

Comment: Clearly it isn't a string. Python does not throw spurious errors in this case. We cannot answer without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

Please put in your example. Though it sounds like you are simply trying to append an int to a string. This is not allowed and has multiple workarounds.

```
mystring += str(myint)
mystring = '%s%d' % (mystring, myint)
mystring = f'{mystring}{myint}'
```

But all of this is meaningless without knowing what your exact problem is

Answer (score -1):

you can use str() to tranform int.

```
str(i)
```